# Indexing all fields (String) of a collection in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb

The below code is used to index all fields that contain string content in the Mongo Shell.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex(
                           { "$**": "text" },
                           { name: "TextIndex" }
                         )
```

Could any one, please tell me how to write the above in Java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Java API is very similar .. call [`ensureIndex()`](http://bit.ly/TKHyw3) with your field spec and options. If that isn't working for you, please update with a code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the current java driver, you could try

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("foo");    
coll.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("$**", "text"));
```

See also for more information.

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/

Comment: I got error when I executed above code:Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoException: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $**

Comment: which version of the java driver and mongodb?  I was using mongo-java-driver-2.12.2  and mongodb v 2.6.3